# Phonegap install facebook plugin error - facebookconnect.xml already exist

Tags: facebook, cordova, plugins

I am trying to install Facebook Plugin using the Automatic Installation section mentioned here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin for phonegap using this command

```
 phonegap plugin add C:\Softwares\phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="240818432XXXXXX" --variable APP_NAME="MyAPPNAME"
```

and i get thie serror

```
[phonegap] adding the plugin: C:\Softwares\phone
[Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME]
[error] Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME
```

So i saw this question and followed it [Cordova Facebook plugin : missing variables APP_ID, APP_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355792/cordova-facebook-plugin-missing-variables-app-id-app-name)

I installed plugman using nodejs and run the command below

```
plugman -d install --platform android --project C:\Users\Documents\myproject 
--plugin C:\Softwares\phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="240818432XXXXXX" 
--variable APP_NAME="MyAPPNAME"
```

and i get this error :

```
Installing "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" for android
cordova version check failed ("C:\Users\Documents\myproject\cordova\version")
, continuing anyways.
Install start for "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" on android.
Beginning processing of action stack for android project...
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect':Error: Uh oh!
"C:\Users\Documents\myproject\res\values\facebookconnect.xml" already exists!
```

I am not sure if i am in the right way on installing facebookplugin for phonegap. I just followed the documentation in phonegap and this is what i get.

I am using windows7 64 bit.

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The project path is wrong. It should point to `\myproject\platforms\android`.
You need to run `phonegap build android` first to build this.

```
plugman -d install --platform android --project C:\Users\Documents\myproject
        --plugin C:\Softwares\phonegap-facebook-plugin
        --variable APP_ID="240818432XXXXXX" --variable APP_NAME="MyAPPNAME"
```