# Cordova Facebook plugin: set APP_ID, APP_NAME in config.xml

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

**1. What we want to achieve**

Install a pre-configured cordova app using fb cordova plugin ( cordova-plugin-facebook4 - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 )

**2. Problem**

The problem derives from the "pre-configured" part. 
As a default, the plugin required to being install passing it some configurations like APP_NAME / APP_ID values, as documentation at < https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook > specified.

This is a problem for us because our application creation flow process is based mainly onto the Cordova's configuration *config.xml* where clearly all plugins are listed.

**3. Question**

Our need is to be able to pass some configuration directly inside the *config.xml* file, like for other plugins here below shown:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.1">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Allow the app to use your camera" />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Allow the app to access your photos" />
</plugin>
```

In the previous lines, variables for cordova-plugin-camera is the way to configure the plugin.

**4. Alternative solutions not adopted**

Reading around, some solution required to change *plugin.xml* file of facebook-plugin.

The problem of this solution is the cost for the forked plugin maintenance.

**5. Question-based on 4.**

Avoiding to fork plugin for configuration setting purpose, can be *HOOKS* approach usefull? I mean, can we replace "preference" tag inside *plugin.xml* at some build / prepare / plugin install time as wrote in the second answer at the following link < [Cordova Facebook plugin : missing variables APP_ID, APP_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355792/cordova-facebook-plugin-missing-variables-app-id-app-name) > ?

**thanks for reading!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the APP_ID and APP_NAME in the config XML as following:-

Under Android Platforms:-

```
<config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
    <string name="fb_app_id">574355309670137</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">HUB App</string>
</config-file>
```

And outside the platform and at the bottom(when installed fb plugin) it would be defined as below:-

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^3.1.0">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="574355309670137" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="HUB App" />
</plugin>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sure!!! 
Before you wrote, i'm trying the second part of your answer (plugin variables), just now starting build :) 

A question in the meanwhile: why the first part for android ? is mandatory ? "fb_app_id" and "fb_app_name" are described / default string name required by fb cordova plugin ?

Thanks

Comment: @SimoneCampagna In Android, if we do not add that part it does not recognize the fb app id and gives an error. This is researched by me and the implementation came once the research was done. I have an app working when I add these variables.

Comment: @SimoneCampagna Any updates on this? Did this solution worked for you?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, and sorry for delay.

Comment: Your solution is OK even if i didn't use the first part (Android requirement for fb_app_id and fb_app_name).

We're currently using cordova-plugin-facebook4 4.2.1 under cordova 7.1.0.
Simone